# Counting data from external source

Tags: python

I am currently pulling data from an external source. I want to count the instances of a certain data point, for example, a genre.

Lets say I have a library of books, and I can pull the genre's of each book. There can be an infinite number of genre's, but I want to know how many of each genre exist in my library.

```
library = [{'Title of the book', 'Genre'}, {'Title of another book', 'Genre2'},etc]
for book in library:
    print book[1] //this is the genre
```

What I'm not sure of is the best way to count the number of books in the genre, given that there can be an infinite number of genres.

I think psuedo code wise, in my mind it looks like this:

```
check list for genre
if genre exists, add to count
else create new list item for genre
```

Whats the most elegant way to do this in python? Is there a better way to keep this count?

Comment: check out the docs for `Counter` from the python `collections` module: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Comment: Can put your data into a pandas Series and use the .value_counts() function.

Comment: Note that the number of genres may be large, but "infinite" may be overstating it a bit.  At the very least it shouldn't be much larger than the number of books.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to count all the occurrences would be to use `Counter`. Something like the following:

```
from collections import Counter

Counter([book[1] for book in library])
```

Comment: if your data is in the set format, then maybe you should use book.pop() instead of book[1].

Answer (score 0):

Your thinking is correct! You can keep count for each genre in a dictionary like this:

```
genre_counts = {}
for book in library:
  genre = book[1]
  genre_counts[genre] = genre_counts.get(genre, 0) + 1
```